# Cypress - Certain table rows (<tr), not shown inside modal window

Tags: dom, modal-dialog, cypress, tablerow, end-to-end

1. I click on a button => Modal window is shown
2. On real app. (DOM) - Inside that modal window we have 4 table rows inside the table body:
   `table > tbody > tr / tr / tr / tr`
3. On Cypress tests (DOM) - Inside that modal window we have 1 table row inside the table body:
   `table > tbody > tr`

[image: Cypress Test]

[image: Real Application]

1. I tried waiting a fixed period before and after i click on the button for the modal window to be shown
2. I tried scrolling initially to the button which triggers the modal window to be opened
3. I tried invoking show both on the modal window and on the needed <tr elements

- Test fails either way when searching for the `#checkboxstrategy0` element (checkbox)
- here is my code (along with what i've tried):

```
cy.scrollElementIntoView('.select-rating-style')
    //cy.wait(10000)
    //cy.clickOption(cy.getField('a', 'class', 'select-rating-style'))
    cy.get('.select-rating-style').click()
    //cy.wait(10000)
    //cy.get('.modal-body').eq(2).should('be.visible')
    //cy.get('.modal-body').eq(2).invoke('show')
    cy.get('#checkboxstrategy0').invoke('show')
```

Comment: Update. The issue is that the requests which are used to retrieve the data i need above come as 403.

For example `GET 403 /api/offering-categories?lang=en`

        cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/offering-categories*').as('categories')


I try to intercept these at the beginning and wait on them when the page loads (when the problem occurs), but no luck

`cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/offering-categories*').as('categories')`  `cy.visit('/myPage)`
 `cy.wait('@strategies').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200)`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the rows are loading asynchronously, and you need to assert the correct number before working with the checkbox.

```js
cy.get('.modal-body')
  .find('tbody tr')
  .should('have.length', 4)

// test checkbox after above passes
```

Comment: No, did further investigation.
I am missing the api requests above to be '200', instead i get '403'.
This happens when i login using `cy.session()` and `cy.request()` inside it, but it's okay when i login using conventional UI approach.

I checked the API calls and they don't have anything special about them, simple GET requests. Works fine for other similar requests i get when visiting my page in question. What am i missing here?